# Network Image Mock not same color between first test and second, third,

Tags: flutter, mockito

first image: [image: 1]

second image : [image: 2]

thrid image : [image: 3]

---

example my code:

```
    await mockNetworkImagesFor(() async {
      final testPage = CircleAvatar(
        radius: Sizes.profilePictureRadius,
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
          HttpConstants.defaultAvatarUrl,
        ),
      );

      await TestUtils.pumpWidget(tester, testPage);

      await expectLater(
          find.byType(Container), matchesGoldenFile('test_01.png'));
    });
```